# Adding Background image to Jumbotron

Tags: visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a background image to the jumbotron and I have seen a lot of examples but nothing seems to work here in the code.

Created css folder under src

`<template>
  <div class="development container">
  <div class="jumbotron mt-3">
   <h1 class="display-3">Sofware Development</h1>`

CSS File code
`.jumbotron mt-3 {
    background-image: url('../empowers/src/assets/team1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;}`

Comment: You have a typo in your css file `.jumbotron mt-3`, give style to `.jumbotron`

Answer (score 2):

```css
.jumbotron{
    background-image: url('http://placehold.jp/006699/cccc00/150x100.png');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <div class="development container">
  <div class="jumbotron mt-3">
   <h1 class="display-3">Sofware Development</h1>
</div>
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you just need to use jumbotron as a class to apply background image over it.

Answer (score 0):

As the below:

```css
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url('http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/assets/brand/bootstrap-social.png');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="development container">
  <div class="jumbotron mt-3">
   <h1 class="display-3">Sofware Development</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```